# Rails app crash when reaching any valid routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crash, rubygems

I have tried to restart my app this week (not an old app, i was pushing new features last week) and I have got a crash when I am visiting any valid routes. I can not understand why it is now crashing.

Here are logs in the terminal :

```
 2981 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/controllers/scoped_views.rb
 2982 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb
 2983 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
 2984 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb
 2985 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb
 2986 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/flows.rb
 2987 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb
 2988 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template/sources.rb
 2989 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/template/sources/file.rb
 2990 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/unbound_template.rb
 2991 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/buffers.rb
 2992 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb
 2993 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/label.rb
 2994 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb
 2995 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/password_field.rb
 2996 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/checkable.rb
 2997 /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.4.1/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/check_box.rb

* Process memory map:

10e0f8000-10e0fc000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby
10e105000-10e108000 r-- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e534000-10e535000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
10e5af000-10e5b2000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/enc/encdb.bundle
10fa55000-10fa58000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
10fa65000-10fa68000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/monitor.bundle
10fa76000-10fa78000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/pathname.bundle
10fa8d000-10fa90000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/stringio.bundle
10faa4000-10faa8000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/digest/md5.bundle
10fab1000-10fab4000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/openssl/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
10fb3f000-10fb40000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
10fdc2000-10fdc4000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/digest.bundle
10fdd0000-10fdd3000 r-- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/digest.bundle
10fdd3000-10fdd4000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/etc.bundle
10fde3000-10fde4000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/fiddle.bundle
10fdf9000-10fdfc000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/socket.bundle
10fe38000-10fe3c000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/io/wait.bundle
10fe45000-10fe48000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/digest/sha1.bundle
10fe55000-10fe58000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/msgpack-1.4.2/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle
10fe76000-10fe78000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.bundle
10fe86000-10fe88000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/zlib.bundle
10fea4000-10fea8000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/psych.bundle
10feb4000-10fecc000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
10fed2000-10fed6000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/strscan.bundle
10fee1000-10fee2000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/date_core.bundle
10ff4c000-10ff4e000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/json/ext/parser.bundle
10ff60000-10ff62000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/json/ext/generator.bundle
10ff76000-10ff7a000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/cgi/escape.bundle
10ff84000-10ff86000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/fiber.bundle
10ff93000-10ff96000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/openssl.bundle
110007000-11000a000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/io/nonblock.bundle
110017000-11001a000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/digest/sha2.bundle
110027000-11002a000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/bigdecimal.bundle
11004b000-11004e000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/racc-1.6.0/lib/racc/cparse.bundle
11005c000-11005e000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.12.5-x86_64-darwin/lib/nokogiri/2.7/nokogiri.bundle
1103d1000-1103d2000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle
11041a000-110452000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.4/lib/libpq.5.13.dylib
110463000-110466000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l_1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
1104e1000-1104e2000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l_1/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
11073a000-11076e000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.19.2/lib/libgssapi_krb5.2.2.dylib
110785000-110786000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.19.2/lib/libkrb5.3.3.dylib
110842000-110866000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.19.2/lib/libk5crypto.3.1.dylib
110872000-110876000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.19.2/lib/libcom_err.3.0.dylib
11087f000-110882000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/krb5/1.19.2/lib/libkrb5support.1.1.dylib
110895000-110896000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle
1108ca000-110a7a000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/libsass.bundle
110c4c000-110c4e000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/enc/windows_31j.bundle
110c5c000-110c5f000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/byebug.bundle
110c75000-110c77000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/readline.bundle
110c89000-110c8b000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.1.1/lib/libreadline.8.1.dylib
110cce000-110ccf000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/ripper.bundle
110d17000-110d1b000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/io/console.bundle
110d26000-110d27000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/lib/skiptrace/internal/cruby.bundle
110d34000-110d37000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin20/enc/utf_16le.bundle
110d54000-110d57000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.8/lib/nio4r_ext.bundle
110d77000-110d7f000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.10/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle
110d8a000-110d8b000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby
110d8b000-110d8c000 r-x /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby
110dad000-110dae000 rw- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby
110dae000-110dbb000 r-- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby
110dbb000-1111ca000 r-- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
1111ca000-111234000 r-- /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
111234000-1115b2000 r-- /Users/remicarette/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/libsass.bundle
11ad07000-11ada3000 r-x /usr/lib/dyld
11ada3000-11adab000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
11adab000-11adaf000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
11adaf000-11ade3000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
11ade3000-11ae1b000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
11ae1b000-11ae1f000 r--

[IMPORTANT]
Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
[1]    7900 abort      rails s
```

I have tried to find an answer on stackoverflow but it is really to understand what causes the crash...

Here is the Gemfile, maybe can help :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.4', '>= 6.0.4.1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'


gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'devise'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '10.2.5'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'simple_form'
group :development, :test do  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'stimulus-rails'

gem 'pg_search', '~> 2.3.0'
gem "view_component", require: "view_component/engine"
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'faker', :git => 'https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker.git', :branch => 'master'
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.16.0'
gem 'letter_opener', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
end

gem 'airrecord'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', '~> 1.0'
```

Thanks for you help !

**✅ EDIT 1 - SOLVED**

I found a solution on github. I works like a charm!

> After adding (and downgrading at same time) gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
> to my Gemfile, on my Rails 6 app, it works again.

Comment: Is it reproducible? Sometimes to restart simply the Rails server (or even computer) solves the problem. Or, version-mismatch of some included binaries may cause this; in that case, to reinstall Ruby and/or Rails may solve the problem. Just suggestions.

Comment: I found this answer on github : https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails/issues/122#issuecomment-607007731

After adding (and downgrading at same time) gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2' to my Gemfile, on my Rails 6 app, it works again.